# Intersect with row dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to intersect a target range with some row, changing dynamically:
I was using this :

```
If Not intersect ([1:7],target) Is Nothing Then
```

And it works, but :

```
Dim n as Integer : n = 7
If Not intersect ([1:n],target) Is Nothing Then
```

Returns Error 424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` syntax is shortcut for [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) :

```
If Not intersect (Evaluate("1:" & n), target) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 5):

`[]` does not allow variables you will need to spell it out:

```
Dim n as Integer : n = 7
If Not intersect (Range("1:" & n),target) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim n As Integer: n = 7

    If Not Intersect(Target, Rows("1:" & n)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "in"
    End If

End Sub
```